# Sum of the cells depending on other cells values while relating to other cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables to register the names of the teachers and their assignments to observe in the tests classes over 5 days:

1. The first table has the names with their observations codes.
   [image]
2. The table containing the relationship of the durations of the subjects.
   [image]

Now, what I want to calculate is the total in the first table, but the way it sums depends on the codes in the left cells with these conditions in mind:

a. Codes 1-4 mean you have to take the subject from the first row (starting with Math and ending with Literature), while the codes 5-8 will take the subject in the second row (starting with Science and ending with Computer).

b. The weight (number of hours) of the subject to be summed is taken from the second table.

Example of how to sum the weights for the first teacher (Albert Pratt):

Day1: 1 -> Math -> 2.5

Day2: 5 -> Math -> 2.5

Day3: 3 -> Science -> 2

Day5: 4 -> Literature -> 2.5

The first total cell will have: 2.5 + 2.5 + 2 + 2.5 = 9.5

Answer (score 0):

It's not very elegant but this will work given the data you have provided where the 2nd table spans from `A1:B6` in `Sheet2`:

```
=SUM(
IF(B3=0,0,INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6,MATCH(INDEX(B$1:B$2,INT(B3/5)+1),Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,0))),
IF(C3=0,0,INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6,MATCH(INDEX(C$1:C$2,INT(C3/5)+1),Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,0))),
IF(D3=0,0,INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6,MATCH(INDEX(D$1:D$2,INT(D3/5)+1),Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,0))),
IF(E3=0,0,INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6,MATCH(INDEX(E$1:E$2,INT(E3/5)+1),Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,0))),
IF(F3=0,0,INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6,MATCH(INDEX(F$1:F$2,INT(F3/5)+1),Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,0))))
```

Use this formula in cell `G3` of your first table and drag down.

Answer (score 0):

Given the 2nd table is on the same sheet on cells `A15:A19` here is your formula for cell `G2`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IF(B3="",0,IF(B3<5,$B$1,$B$2)),$A$15:$B$19,2,0),0) + 
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IF(C3="",0,IF(C3<5,$C$1,$C$2)),$A$15:$B$19,2,0),0) + 
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IF(D3="",0,IF(D3<5,$D$1,$D$2)),$A$15:$B$19,2,0),0) + 
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IF(E3="",0,IF(E3<5,$E$1,$E$2)),$A$15:$B$19,2,0),0) + 
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IF(F3="",0,IF(F3<5,$F$1,$F$2)),$A$15:$B$19,2,0),0)
```

[image]